# [Remote-SSH Bug]: Remote Extension host terminated unexpectedly three times within the last five minutes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am connecting to my remote machine using the Remote-SSH extension in Visual Studio Code. Also I installed the C/C++ extension.
Whenever the C/C++ extension is enabled, I am getting:

`Remote Extension host terminated unexpectedly 3 times within the last 5 minutes.`

Output channel log for Remote-ssh:

`2023-10-11 18:23:18.287 [error] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, open '/home/admin1/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/79bbbc13aa7934293eb28938bdd9920c/vscode.lock'`

I tried with `rm rf.vscode-server`, but it is not working.